# Row Curly Brackets

Tags: arrays, brackets

Could you help me please to write this on latex ?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe you should have a look at the `\underbrace`/`\overbrace` commands.

Comment: The problem is that I am dealing with arrays, not with normal text. I know how to use these comments in the normal text, but I don't know how to use these comments here. Many columns entries have the same underbrace. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution with the `\mathclap` command from `mathtools`, applied to a `matrix` environment nested in `pmatrix`. Also, note the correct `\coloneqq` instead of `:=` (the latter has the colon not centred on the math axis).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathbf{B}_j \coloneqq
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dotsm & 0 & b^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm \\
 & \mathclap{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}0 & \dotsm & 0\end{matrix}}_{\left\lceil\frac{d}{2}\right\rceil = \ell_2}} & & 0 & 0 & b^{-1} & 0 &\dotsm \\[-1ex]
 & & & & & & & \ddots \\[-1ex]
 & & & & & & & b^{-1} & \overbrace{\begin{matrix}0 & \dotsm & 0\end{matrix}}^{\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\right\rfloor = \ell_1}
  \end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you already have answer on similar question ... considering *AboAmmar* answer and *epR8GaYuh* comment above and your claim, that you are familiar with `\underbrace` should not be difficult to construct your wished matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5em}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
  \left(
\begin{array}{lcr}
\underbrace{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      0  &  \dots & 0  \\
      0  &  \dots & 0
    \end{array}}_{\left\lceil\frac i2\right\rceil=\ell_1}
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      b^{-1} & 0 & 0      & 0  \\  
      0      & 0 & b^{-1} & 0
    \end{array}     &           &               \\
                    & \ddots    &               \\
                    &           &
\overbrace{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      b^{-1} & \dots & 0 
    \end{array}}^{\left\lceil\frac i2\right\rceil=\ell_2}
\end{array}
\right)
\] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some matrix nesting; we need `array` so we can use the `[t]` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{B}_j \coloneqq
\begin{pmatrix}
\smash[b]{
  \underbrace{
    \begin{array}[t]{@{\,}ccc@{}}
    0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \dots & 0
    \end{array}
  }_{\left\lceil\frac{d}{2}\right\rceil=\ell_2}
} &
\begin{array}[t]{@{}ccccccc@{\,}}
b^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & b^{-1} & 0 & \dots \\
  &   &        &   & \ddots \\
  &   &        &   &        & b^{-1} &
  \smash[t]{
    \overbrace{
      \begin{matrix}
      0 & \dots & 0
      \end{matrix}
    }^{\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\right\rfloor = \ell_1}
  }
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `\smash` the height of the material for `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` is ignored.

[image]

You can give a bit more air by adding some vertical space:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{B}_j \coloneqq
\begin{pmatrix}
\smash[b]{
  \underbrace{
    \begin{array}[t]{@{\,}ccc@{}}
    0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \dots & 0
    \end{array}
  }_{\left\lceil\frac{d}{2}\right\rceil=\ell_2}
} &
\begin{array}[t]{@{}ccccccc@{\,}}
b^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & b^{-1} & 0 & \dots \\[1ex]
  &   &        &   & \ddots \\[1ex]
  &   &        &   &        & b^{-1} &
  \smash[t]{
    \overbrace{
      \begin{matrix}
      0 & \dots & 0
      \end{matrix}
    }^{\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\right\rfloor = \ell_1}
  }
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]